# Do I need a regular expression in C for this string comparison

Tags: c, regex

I need all strings starting KAS. For example  KAS, KASDGFT, KASddfdd etc.
But in my case it is just KAS. It does not look at KASGHFJHFT, but it starts with KAS. So I need it. I thought to add a regular expression which means nothing or something after KAS like KAS* in `strcmp`. But it did not work; what should I be doing?

```
int function (double a, int b, char *program)
{
   if (strcmp(program,"KAS")==0){
       if (cgpa >= 2 && courses_complete >= 5) {
          return 1;
       }
   } else if (cgpa >= 3 && courses_complete >= 8) {
       return 1;
   } 
   return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using `strcmp`, use `strncmp` which compares the first n characters.

For example, `if (strncmp(program,"KAS",3)==0)`

Answer (score 0):

None of the standard C string functions support regular expressions; you'll have to use something outside of the standard C library (such as the [GNU extensions](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html)) for regular expression matching.

If you only need to search for the substring `"KAS"`, though, you can use `strstr`:

```
if ( strstr( program, "KAS" ) )
{
  // program contains substring "KAS"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Cannot agree any more with Vicky, 
and I try to write the function strncmp

```
int my_strncmp(const char* str1, const char* str2, unsigned int num)
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    for( ; (*str1==*str2)&&(*str1!='\0')&&(i<num-1); str1++, str2++, i++)
        ;
    return *str1-*str2;
}
```

hope can be help

Comment: Why not just the use the n in strncmp? ;) Like `if (strncmp(program,"KAS",3)==0){....}` as proposed by Vicky?

Comment: Note: `strncmp(str1,str2,0)` is well defined - returns 0;.  `my_strncmp(str1,str2,0)` would function like `strcmp(str1,str2)`.  Avoid subtraction with `unsigned` parameters.

Comment: chux's note is really helpful! It seems that  i<num-1  will not function well if num is 0...